# JavaScript get variable in current scope by name

Tags: javascript

So I have a variable and a string of that variable name

```
function Factory(string) {
  var foo = 'bar'
  console.log("foo is equal to " + this[string])
}
```

how can I get the variable from the string literal, if the object the variable is on is the current one?

I thought the code would work, but the following happens:

```
var f = new Factory('foo') //=> "foo is equal to undefined"
```

How can I get the variable from the string literal?

Answer (score 2):

`this[string]` assumes that you have a variable `this.foo` which you don't.

---

You can do some `eval`  manipulation if you want, which will work in your case:

```
function Factory(string) {
  var foo = 'bar'
  console.log("foo is equal to " + eval('(function(){return ' + string + '})()'))
}
```

Comment: I know I don't, I'm still trying to get the variable though.

Comment: oh I didn't think of that! Can you also just do `eval('foo')`?

Comment: @JacksonGariety: Looks like an XY problem, you don't typically do this in JS... What are you trying to do exactly? What's the bigger picture?

Comment: @JacksonGariety `eval` will only run some code. `eval('foo')` won't do anything.

Comment: I agree @elclanrs Very odd.

Comment: @elclanrs I have JSON coming down and need to create an instance from the JSON, but each JSON requires a different model. The JSON has a key called "name" and the model constructors are all variables by that name. I'm trying to avoid using a switch statement.

Comment: I don't like eval. eval is evil.

Comment: I do not like it either @BernardoPacheco but in this case it is the only thing that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

while you can use `eval`, i believe the proper approach is to use an object:

```js
function Factory(string) {
  var variables = {foo: 'bar'};
  console.log(string + " is equal to " + variables[string])
}
```